# How do I change the array index in javascript (not the value)

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I need to change the index value in javascript

let say

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

with index 0-banana,1-Orange,2-Apple,3-Mango

What I want is to change these index values say 345-Banana,346-Orange,347-Apple, 348-Mango .

let me know if there is any  quick way to do it , it will reduce some of my conversion code .. Otherwise I have to keep track of index (0,1,2,3) to values(345,346...)

I will store index value in my db, array value is just to display on UI (just like select box)

Comment: You're sure an object wouldn't be more suitable than an array for that ?

Comment: I m using some third party tool for UI ,that method takes only array and array index sets as the value to input field .  So Just I thought if changing index so everything falls into place

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gXSZ2/

Comment: But jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gXSZ2 is not a good approach

Answer (score 2):

So why are you using `Array`. Use `Map` and give any custom key(index) value.

```
var map = new Object(); // or var map = {};
map[myKey1] = myObj1;
map[myKey2] = myObj2;

function get(k) {
    return map[k];
}
```

Or if not want to use Map, don't change the index just set the value of input field by

```
<input type="" value="<any base value like 350>+index"/>
```

I think this can help.

Comment: I m using some third party tool for UI ,that method takes only array and array index sets as the value to input field . So Just I thought if changing index so everything falls into place

Comment: @ULLASK I think you wrote comment in wrong answer. According to my answer, you don't have to change the array index just customize the value field of input element.(see the answer)

Comment: ya ya by mistake I put that comment ..I removed it now

Answer (score 1):

you need to use associative array.

```
var fruits= new Array();
fruits['345'] = 'banana';
fruits['346'] = 'Orange';
fruits['347'] = 'Apple';
fruits['348'] = 'Mango'; 

for (var i in fruits) {
    alert('index is: ' + i + ', value is: ' + fruits[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use enum like :

var fruits = { 345 : "Banana", 346 : "Orange",347 : "Apple", 348 : "Mango"};

console.log(fruits[345]);

Answer (score 0):

Give the Fruits array a starting index

```
let fruits = new Array();
fruits[345] = "banana";   // initial index
fruits.push("orange" , "apple" , "mango")
console.log(fruits[346]); // orange
```